# Assembly.Load causes AccessViolationException

Tags: boost, dll, c++-cli, access-violation, loadmodule

using c# i'm trying to load a dll written in C++/Cli, i used the following command:

`Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);`

previously it has worked with no issues and i'm not exactly sure what changed but today i started getting the following error whenever i tried to load the dll

> System.AccessViolationException: {"Attempted to read or write
>   protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is
>   corrupt."}

Both the dll and the code reading it are in the same solution and the dll itself is often changed (hence why i use dll).

does anyone have any idea what could cause this exception?

addendum:

I've narrowed it down to a lib I recently added which uses boost.
i used `BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC` and found it uses the following:

> Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib
>
> Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib
>
> Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib
>
> Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib

Found a [boost](http://marc.info/?l=boost-users&m=123425857320026&w=2) post which seems to deal with a similar issue, but did not actually solve my problem.
it says to use the `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` preprocessor definition but all that does is cause further linkage errors:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib'

Comment: Could it be that the dll is not compiling correctly?

Comment: it compiles correctly i think otherwise there wouldn't be a dll. in any case I am compiling it in a separate project, which produces a 1.7 MB dll.

Comment: Try starting your application as an admin.

Comment: Just did, unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved in the most obvious of ways.

downloaded and compiled boost from the top, got all the missing files (which for some reason were missing from my folder).

so in summary:
added the `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` preprocessor definition, recompiled boost to get all the missing files and made sure the dll's were in the appropriate folder.